# HTTP 404 error ( After Enable anonymous access )

Tags: sharepoint-site

I have strange issue that I have one a site collection with port (80) and I would like to enable anonymous access from Central administrator --> Manage web application --> Select web application (80) --> Authentications providers --> Default --> Enable anonymous access -- > Save.

After that the site doesn't working! show to me the below screen :
[image]

Could you please support me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check your site in IIS, sometimes this change causes the site to "Stop".  If you see it stopped in IIS, then restarting the site, and possibly performing an `iisreset` should get your site back.